# Strongly continuous one-parameter unitary group and the form domain of the generator

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators, sesquilinear-forms

Suppose $A :D(A) \subset \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is self-adjoint over the separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. By Stone's Theorem, $A$ generates a unique one-parameter strongly continuous group $U(t) = \exp(-itA)$ of unitary operators. It is a standard fact that $U(t)$ preserves the domain of $A$, i.e., $U(t)[D(A)] \subset D(A)$.

Suppose now $A$ is also semibounded from below, i.e., $A + \mu\mathrm{Id} \geq 0$ for some $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, so that $A$ it is associated with a unique bounded sesquilinear form $a : Q(A) \times Q(A) \to \mathcal{H}$, where $Q(A) = D((A+\mu \mathrm{Id})^{1/2}) \supset D(A)$ is the form domain of $A$. (On $D(A)$, $a(u,v) = \langle u,Av\rangle$.)

**Question**: Does $U(t)$ also preserve the form domain, i.e.,

$$ U(t)[Q(A)] \subset Q(A) \quad ? $$

Comment: Does the domain of $Q(A)$ coincide with $D((A+aI)^{1/2})$ in case $A+aI\ge 0$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, precisely. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing $A$ with $A+\mu I$ we may assume that $A\ge 0.$ Let $E(x)$ denote the resolution of the identity associated with $A.$ Then
$$D(A^{1/2})=\left\{v\in \mathcal{H}\,:\, \int\limits_{0^-}^\infty x\,d\langle E(x)v,v\rangle <\infty\right \}$$
The operators $e^{itA}$ commute with $E(x),$ hence
$$\langle E(x)e^{itA}v,e^{itA}v\rangle =\langle e^{-itA}E(x)e^{itA}v,v\rangle =\langle E(x)v,v\rangle\quad (*) $$

Let $v\in D(A^{1/2}).$ Then, in view of $(*),$ for $w=e^{itA}v$ we have
$$\int\limits_{0^-}^\infty x\,d\langle E(x)w,w\rangle=
\int\limits_{0^-}^\infty x\,d\langle E(x)v,v\rangle <\infty $$
Hence $w\in D(A^{1/2}).$

Comment: Looks good! Will digest this and return

Comment: In the def of $D(A^{1/2}$, is it not $x^1$ that is supposed to go under the integral sign, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to square the function. Re-edit instantly

Comment: The argument seems simple, and it seems the key is the proper understanding of the spectral theorem. It seems to me this argument will work with much more general $f(A)$, am I right?

Comment: You are right. I have based on the formula $(5.11)$ on page $92$ of K. Schmudgen, Unbounded
Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space, which describes the domain of $f(A)$ as $$D(f(A))=\left \{v\,:\, \int |f(x)|^2\,d\langle E(x)v,v\rangle <\infty \right \}$$ say for continuous functions on the real line.  Perhaps in the particular case of $A^{1/2}$ the spectral theorem can be avoided. At the moment I do not have any idea how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! You have been very helpful.